# Field validation error on nodereference field during D6 to D7 migration

Tags: entities, migrations, nodes

I'm migrating a D6 site to D7.

There are several content types that have cck noderefenrce fields that use referenced views for content types that can be referenced.

When I run the migration, I get a field validation error:

> Field validation error for field: field name: this post can't be referenced.

In the CLI, I've used `--user=1` to see if it was a permissions problem, but no luck.

Has anyone experienced this? Any hints or suggestions?

Comment: Please post your migration class so we can take a look.

Comment: I'm using the Migrate module out of the box with configured field mappings and running the migrations from the cli. I only wrote one custom migration and that was for the files.

Comment: The error is thrown in:
migrate\plugins\destinations\entity.inc: field_attach_validate($entity_type, $entity); in static public function fieldAttachValidate($entity_type, $entity);

Comment: What content type contains the node/entity reference?  What content type does that reference point to?  At the time the content containing the node reference is migrated has the migration for the content it's referencing already been run?

Comment: **What content type contains the node/entity reference?** It references a Multimedia content type. **What content type does that reference point to?** It points to a Multimedia node. **At the time the content containing the node reference is migrated has the migration for the content it's referencing already been run?** Yes. Thanks! I should add the nodereference field keeps the source node id of the node rather than the new node id after it has been migrated.

Comment: I think you misunderstood one of my questions:  From your response I understand the nodereference field *references* multimedia content, but what type of content actually has the nodereference field on it?  Is it, say, a basic page that's referencing multimedia content?

Comment: The content type is actually named "Multimedia", it holds various types of multimedia content. The content with the nodereference field is a node with different content but a basic page. Also, I'm getting the same error on several nodereference fields. Thanks again.

Comment: We're still miscommunicating. You have content type 1 that references content type 2.  I know content type 2 is called "Multimedia".  I'd like to know what content type 1 is.  That said, I don't want to waste your time.  It doesn't look like there's support for migrating nodereference fields in D2D migrate.  You'll need to write a custom migrate class.  In general, I haven't had much luck with the D2D GUI; it's only useful for super-simple migrations.

Comment: Writing a custom migration class (especially if you're using migrate_d2d) is really quite easy to do and a worthy exercise.  Take a look at the migrate_d2d_example code.  The nice thing is that migrate keeps track of the mapping between the old NIDs and the new so that you need only write one line of code in your constructor to ensure the reference field has the right value: https://www.drupal.org/node/2086537

Comment: Cool! At this point it's worth going for it. I've written some before it seems like I keep coming back to this solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there's support for migrating nodereference fields in D2D migrate. You'll need to write a custom migrate class. In general, I haven't had much luck with the D2D GUI; it's only useful for super-simple migrations.

Writing a custom migration class (especially if you're using `migrate_d2d`) is really quite easy to do and a worthy exercise. Take a look at the `migrate_d2d_example` code. The nice thing is that migrate keeps track of the mapping between the old NIDs and the new so that you need only write one line of code in your constructor to ensure the reference field has the right value.

See: [Migrate D6 node reference to D7 entityreference](http://drupal.org/node/2086537)